# Problem in finding the first term and common difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the first $6$ terms of an arithmetic sequence is $96$. The sum of the first $10$ terms is one third of the sum of first $20$ terms. I tried to equate the sum of the first $10$ terms and $20$ terms by using the unknowns from the sum of six terms but i still can get the answer which is $a=11$, $d=2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE .If you are not posting your attempt, your question will be considered as Home Work question which is usually not well received here .

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic sequence equal to
$$
S_n=\frac{2a+d(n-1)}{2}n.
$$
You have
$$
S_6=96\\
3S_{10}=S_{20}.
$$
Ok,
$$
3(2a + 5d) = 96,\\
3\cdot 5(2a+9d) = 10(2a+19d),
$$
or
$$
2a+5d=32,\\
3(2a+9d)=2(2a+19d)\Longrightarrow 2a - 11d= 0.
$$
Could you proceed?

Comment: Yes i can proceed